# Neo4j rest client in Java

Tags: java, rest, concurrency, neo4j

I want to access **Neo4j** db concurrently through a rest client in java.

I have already found two clients **neo4j-rest-graphdb 2.0.1** and **neo4j-jdbc 2.3.2** .

Since first one is no longer maintained I'm afraid to go with it.

Can someone please tell me what is the best java rest client for Neo4j which support concurrent access?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [Neo4j-OGM](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm)

> Neo4j OGM is a fast object-graph mapping library for Neo4j, optimised for server-based installations and utilising Cypher via the transactional HTTP endpoint.

It's created and maintained by Neo4j team.

Concurrency is managed by Neo4j itself, you can use any client without worrying for concurrency problem.

Comment: Sorry I miss this in my original post, in our application we allow users to create new nodes and node properties. In Neo4j-OGM it should have pre defined set of classes for all the node types isn't it?

Comment: Yes it does, so I think you have to use jdbc.